# Three.js -- Cannot assign material to a object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a noob in three.js and I just got started recently. Here's my problem, I try to assign a material to an object, but it doesn't work.

```
var objloader=new THREE.OBJLoader();
var material=new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
objloader.load('man.obj', function(object) {
    object.position.y=-30;
    object.material= material;
    scene.add(object);
    render();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign materials to Meshes. The object you're assigning to might not be a mesh... but it might have the mesh as a child..
.
You can do

```
object.traverse( ( obj ) => {

    if ( obj instanceof THREE.Mesh ) obj.material = material;

} );
```

To set the material of all mesh children of that object.

Comment: Or `( obj.isMesh )`.